# How to remove the autocompletion of email in the TextFormField when i type characters such as "." or "@"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created input fields using the TextFormField widget. When i type email that has already been used before, the field just enters the email along with the typed part. This happens when i type characters such as "." or "@". For eg:
Consider an email : "abcd.efgh@abcd.com".
When i type "abcd." the field adds the email again as "abcd.abcd.efgh@".

```
child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 11.5,
                  // height: 45.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[50].withOpacity(0.9),
                      border: new Border.all(color: Colors.grey[100]),
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    autofocus: false,
                    autovalidate: false,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Email',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting autocorrect and/or enableSuggestions properties of TextFormField to false. Both of those are enabled by default.

Comment: thanks. looks like turning off enableSuggestions helped.